# Three Dimensional Plot of Numerical Integral with Delta Function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I want to plot the definite integral of the following function

```
    Integrand[p_, Q2_, ν_, θ_] := p^2/(M^2 (M - 2*E3[p])^2) 
    1/(E3[p] E4[p, Q2, ν, θ]) 1/D[f[p, Q2, ν, θ], p] 
    DiracDelta[p - p3zero1[Q2, ν, θ]]+p^2/(M^2 (M - 2*E3[p])^2) 
    1/(E3[p] E4[p, Q2, ν, θ]) 1/D[f[p, Q2, ν, θ], p] 
    DiracDelta[p - p3zero2[Q2, ν, θ]]
```

Where the integration over `p` runs from `0` to `Infinity` and the integration over `θ` runs from `0` to `Pi`. The definitions of `p3zero1` and `p3zero2` are bad enough that I can't analytically integrate the function and I don't know a priori if they are always greater or smaller than 0 for all points on the integration region. I then came up with the following code to plot it.

```
    Plot3D[NIntegrate[Integrand[p, Q2, ν, θ], {p, 0, Infinity},
    {θ, 0, π}], {Q2, 0, 5000}, {ν, 0, 2000}]
```

The problem that I'm facing is that the Dirac delta function is not defined for numerical integrals. Numerical integrations of Dirac deltas appear to always return 0. But I need a way to plot the function in terms of `Q2` and `ν`.

Thanks.

Comment: [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function) and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) say nothing about any integrals of the $\delta$-distribution over the positive ray of  the real axis. As I know it, such integrals make no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Integrate` can be used to handle the `DiracDelta`,

```
Integrate[Integrand[p, Q2, ν, θ], {p, 0, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> p3zero2[Q2, ν, θ] ∈ Reals && p3zero1[Q2, ν, θ] ∈ Reals]
(* ((HeavisideTheta[p3zero1[Q2, ν, θ]]*p3zero1[Q2, ν, θ]^2)/
   ((M - 2*E3[p3zero1[Q2, ν, θ]])^2*E3[p3zero1[Q2, ν, θ]]*
   E4[p3zero1[Q2, ν, θ], Q2, ν, θ]*Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][f][p3zero1[Q2, ν, θ], Q2, ν, θ]) 
   + (HeavisideTheta[p3zero2[Q2, ν, θ]]*p3zero2[Q2, ν, θ]^2)/
   ((M - 2*E3[p3zero2[Q2, ν, θ]])^2*E3[p3zero2[Q2, ν, θ]]*
   E4[p3zero2[Q2, ν, θ], Q2, ν, θ]*Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][f][p3zero2[Q2, ν, θ], Q2, ν, θ]))
   /M^2 *)
```

However, `NIntegrate` will not work for the remaining integrand, unless all symbols except `θ` are given numerical values.  This can be done by creating a `Table` in `Q2` and `ν` of integrals over `θ`, which then can be plotted with `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: I should have thought of this. The indefinite integral will get rid of the delta functions, as you had said. You can however plot a numerical integral such as the one that I have given above since the Plot function inputs values for Q2 and nu into the argument. Try something like Plot[NIntegrate[c*x, {c, 0, Pi}], {x, 0, 10}].

Comment: @JohnTerry  Indeed so,  Well done.